# Why does `minmax` take longer than a consecutive `min` and `max`?

Tags: matlab

Well basically the question says it all, my intuition tells me that a call to `minmax` should take less time than calling a `min` and then a `max`.

Is there some optimization I prevent Matlab carrying out in the following code?

**minmax:**

```
function minmax_vals = minmaxtest()
    buffSize = 1000000;
    A = rand(128,buffSize);
    windowSize = 100;
    minmax_vals = zeros(128,buffSize/windowSize*2);
    for i=1:(buffSize/windowSize)
        minmax_vals(:,(2*i-1):(2*i)) = minmax(A(:,((i-1)*windowSize+1):(i*windowSize)));
    end
end
```

[image]

**separate min-max:**

```
function minmax_vals = minmaxtest()
    buffSize = 1000000;
    A = rand(128,buffSize);
    windowSize = 100;
    minmax_vals = zeros(128,buffSize/windowSize*2);
    for i=1:(buffSize/windowSize)
        minmax_vals(:,(2*i-1)) = min(A(:,((i-1)*windowSize+1):(i*windowSize)),[],2);
        minmax_vals(:,(2*i)) = max(A(:,((i-1)*windowSize+1):(i*windowSize)),[],2);
    end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Summary

You can see the overhead because `minmax` isn't completely obfuscated. Simply type

```
edit minmax
```

And you will see the function!

---

It appears that there is a data-type conversion to `nntype.data('format',x,'Data');`, which will not be the case for `min` or `max` and could be costly. This is for use with MATLAB's neural networking (nn) tools as `minmax` belongs to that toolbox.

In short, `min` and `max` are lower-level, *compiled* functions (hence they *are* fully obfuscated), which don't require functionality from the nn toolbox.

---

#### Benchmark

Here is a slightly more isolated benchmark, without your windowing and using `timeit` instead of the profiler. **I've also included timings for just the data conversion used in `minmax`!** The test gets the min and max of each row in a large matrix, see here the output plot and code below...

[image: benchmark]

It appears that there is a linear relationship between number of rows and time taken (as expected for a linear operator), but the coefficient is much greater for the combined `minmax` relationship, **with the separate operations being approximately 10x quicker.** Also you can clearly see that data conversion takes more time that the `min` then `max` version alone!

```
function benchie()
    K = zeros(10, 3);
    for k = 1:10        
        n = 2^k;
        A = rand(n, 200);   
        Arow = zeros(1,200); 
        m = zeros(n,2);
        
        f1 = @()minmaxtest(A,m);
        K(k,1) = timeit(f1);

        f2 = @()minthenmaxtest(A,m);
        K(k,2) = timeit(f2);
        
        f3 = @()dataconversiontest(A, Arow);
        K(k,3) = timeit(f3);
    end
    figure; hold on; plot(2.^(1:10), K(:,1)); plot(2.^(1:10), K(:,2)); plot(2.^(1:10), K(:,3));
end
function minmaxtest(A,m)
    for ii = 1:size(A,1)
        m(ii, 1:2) = minmax(A(ii,:));
    end
end
function dataconversiontest(A, Arow)
    for ii = 1:size(A,1)
       Arow = nntype.data('format', A(ii,:), 'Data');;
    end    
end
function minthenmaxtest(A,m)
    for ii = 1:size(A,1)
        m(ii, 1) = min(A(ii,:));
        m(ii, 2) = max(A(ii,:));
    end
end
```